# Why the paragraph is hidden behind navbar however navbar comes first in html source?

Tags: html, css, nav

I dont know but my paragraph goes behind of my navbar I am new in html and css
Below is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> First App </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href ="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class = "a"> <a href = "#"> Google </a></li>
                <li class = "b"> <a href = "#"> Youtube </a></li>
                <li> <a href = "#"> Facebook </a></li>
                <li> <input type="text"> <button> Press Here </button></li> 
            </ul>
        </nav>
   </header>
    <p> 
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicin
        g elit. Est tempora quasi ipsum commodi
        . Atque ut officia magnam et eaqu
        e dolorum incidunt? Hic eos
         ipsam assumenda itaque dese
         runt voluptas porro libero?
     </p>            
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-color:white;
}

nav {
    background-color:blue;
    position:fixed ;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    margin:10px;
    color:white;
}

li.b:hover {
    border-bottom:red;
}
```

[Here's the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVx6v.png)

Okay as you can see the text is hidden behind the navbar, I don't know why this happens. Also, I'm a beginner in HTML and CSS.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because `nav` has been assigned `position: fixed` to the top , so now whatever the height of `nav` is occupied on the screen that will remain `fixed` i.e. allocated to it no matter what and other content on the body will operate in normal behavior neglecting the position of `nav` so assigning a `padding` space equal to the `nav` `height` may resolve the issue.

```css
body {
    background-color:white;
}

nav {
    background-color:blue;
    /* happening because of this */
    position:fixed ;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    margin:10px;
    color:white;
}
/* add this */
p{
padding-top: 75px;
}



li.b:hover {
    border-bottom:red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> First App </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href ="style.css">



</head>
<body>
   <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class = "a"> <a href = "#"> Google </a></li>
                <li class = "b"> <a href = "#"> Youtube </a></li>
                <li> <a href = "#"> Facebook </a></li>
                <li> <input type="text"> <button> Press Here </button></li>

            </ul>

        </nav>


   </header>
  
    <p> 
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicin
        g elit. Est tempora quasi ipsum commodi
        . Atque ut officia magnam et eaqu
        e dolorum incidunt? Hic eos
         ipsam assumenda itaque dese
         runt voluptas porro libero?
         Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicin
         g elit. Est tempora quasi ipsum commodi
         . Atque ut officia magnam et eaqu
         e dolorum incidunt? Hic eos
          ipsam assumenda itaque dese
          runt voluptas porro libero?
          Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicin
        g elit. Est tempora quasi ipsum commodi
        . Atque ut officia magnam et eaqu
        e dolorum incidunt? Hic eos
         ipsam assumenda itaque dese
         runt voluptas porro libero?
         Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicin
         g elit. Est tempora quasi ipsum commodi
         . Atque ut officia magnam et eaqu
         e dolorum incidunt? Hic eos
          ipsam assumenda itaque dese
          runt voluptas porro libero?
         
        </p>
    
           
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, it really helped me! So padding 75px means start paragraph after 75px from top of page?

Comment: yes so padding will consume the height of the navbar and neatly display your paragraph from top @Migo